# post request from one container to another on same network

Tags: angular, docker, containers

I have 2 containers on the same network(they can ping each other). The first Container has port 3000 exposed and is the UI. When it communicates with the api in another container, nothing happens. Nothing is returned.

If i were to access the api(using postman) from the exposed external port 4000, it works.
http://localhost:4000/api/v1.0/Token/AuthenticateByUsernamePassword

I want the containers to communicate on the same network.

If i inspect the network request from the browser:

Request URL:http://172.21.0.4/api/v1.0/Token/AuthenticateByUsernamePassword

Request method:OPTIONS

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

I have tried replacing the ip address with the container name, still nothing. This would only work if i change the ip address to localhost:4000

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: How are they networked together? Are you using docker-compose, etc.? And when you ping one container from the other, what command do you run?

Comment: Yes. I use docker compose. I used docker exec -it then ping other container.

Comment: The issue is probably in your docker-compose file, can you share the relevant parts? And are you running Docker for Mac, or on Linux?

Comment: Im using linux containers in a windows VM
Here is my compose file
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AgFwqOQe4DJagaRXjmgBGF02KotauA?e=ejZL3Q

Comment: Could this be a cors issue?

Comment: I can also confirm I can pull back a get request by using curl on the API container from the UI container

Comment: if it's just the OPTIONS request that's failing, that sure sounds like CORS. i take it you can use curl to reach, e.g. http://mstorebossystem:80 from inside mstorebospricing, so they are networked together, but your requests are failing for some other reason?